# What if I want to write another function?

Tags: c

```
int main(){

    const int length = 30;
    const int width = 20;
    const char newline = '\n';

    int area;

    area = length * width;

    if( length < width){
    printf("the size of this property : %d", area);
    printf("%c", newline);

    } else if(length > width){
        for(int n = 0; n<2; n++){
            printf("miao\n");
        }
    } else{
        for(int i =0; i < 3; i++){
            printf("haooo\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to write another function after it that isn't called main and it didn't run it, why so?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  There are MANY C tutorials on the web.  Please do some research before posting questions here, we are not teachers.  Refer to the guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Only the `main` function runs by itself. To run another function, you have to call it.

For example:

```
void not_main() {

}

int main() {
   not_main();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void` means empty, emptiness. It is used to say that a function does not return anything. Stackoverflow is not a learning site, you can find many tutorials online.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!